# Msql database is not starting XAMPP in mac

Tags: mysql, macos, xampp, connectivity

MySQL database not starting XAMPP in  Mac.when I start running MySQL database shows like this:

[image]

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: i was using xampp for more than 4 months in mac but it just gone wrong today i donno the exact reason . I have tried a lot but not working at all ..i . tried in Terminal codes too

Comment: i cannot bind port 3306

Comment: sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start returns
Starting MySQL
. ERROR!

Comment: i also tried by reinstalling it more than 3 times but it didnt help

Comment: If your question is about code, you should try to debug your code and find a minimal example that we can use to reproduce it. If it's not about code, you should post it in another site in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64414342/mysql-service-database-not-starting-xampp-in-mac-no-message-solved/64414343#64414343

Answer (score 2):

Try to uninstall it and install it again. If it doesn't work for you, you might need to change permission for this. Use `chmod 755 command in /Applications/Xampp/.`

I hope it will sort out your problem, this is how it worked for me.